# How to Link Third node with the First node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to link the Third or Last node with the first node using a Cypher query. Here is my query for two nodes.

```
CREATE  (s1:subject1 {name:'Ali'})-[:went_to]->(o1:object{name: 'Islamabad'})
```

Comment: What is the third node and where do you want to link it?

Comment: After the second node, I want to add the third node and link with the first node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some solutions :

```
CREATE (n1:node)-[:rel]->(n2:node)-[:rel]->(n3:node), (n1)-[:rel]->(n3)
```

or

```
CREATE (n1:node)-[:rel]->(n2:node), (n1)-[:rel]->(n3:node)
```

depending of what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Muldec's Answer.

**You can separately create nodes and relationships to make it simple.**

```
CREATE  (s1:subject {name:'Ali'}), 
    (o1:object {name: 'Islamabad'}),
    (o2:object {name: 'Islamabad-2'}),
    (s1)-[:went_to]->(o1),
    (s1)-[:went_to]->(o2);
```

Comment: **P.S.**: don't write subect1, subject2, etc it will create too many labels. Instead, use s1, s2 for reference and keep the label `subject`. As I used for objects in the above example